# Disk writing percentage on linux

Tags: linux, process

How can I get what process uses disk(hdd). In windows there is `Disk` tab in task manager.

Don't pay attention to that arrow, I found a random image from the web.
[image: D]

I really like `htop` but it does not show disk usage.

How can I get what processes use disk and how much of its power?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Iotop](http://linux.die.net/man/1/iotop) should let you do that - it needs elevated permissions, but displays your disk reads and writes, as well as swap use.

[image]